# how to convert 2D to 1D array in C when int has hexadecimal

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have to change this code of 2D array to 1D array but i am not sure how to do it. Because the values of the 2D arrays are in hexadecimal.

```
int Sbox[SIZE_A][SIZE_B] = { //two dimensional array
{
    0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b,
    0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76
}, //*  initializers for row indexed by 0 
{
    0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf,
    0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0
}, //*  initializers for row indexed by 1
{
    0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1,
    0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15
}, //*  initializers for row indexed by 2
{
    0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2,
    0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75
}, {
    0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3,
    0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84
}, {
    0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39,
    0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf
}, {
    0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f,
    0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8
}, {
    0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21,
    0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2
}, {
    0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d,
    0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73
}, {
    0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14,
    0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb
}, {
    0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62,
    0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79
}, {
    0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea,
    0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08
}, {
    0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f,
    0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a
}, {
    0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9,
    0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e
}, {
    0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9,
    0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf
}, {
    0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f,
    0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16
}
};
```

I want to parse the exact values 0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, etc into the 1D array. So I thought of changing the int to string first, then read out the string as 0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, etc to the 1D array. Any help on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code (both row-major and column-major order variants - please see comments in the code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define A_SIZE 2
#define B_SIZE 3

int main() {
  int values_2d[A_SIZE][B_SIZE] = {{0x12, 0x24, 0x46},{0x13,0x35, 0x57}};
  int values_1d[A_SIZE*B_SIZE]  = {0};
  int i,j;

  for (i = 0; i < A_SIZE; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < B_SIZE; j++) {
      printf("v[%d,%d]=0x%02X\n", i, j, values_2d[i][j]);
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < A_SIZE*B_SIZE; i++) {
    values_1d[i] = values_2d[i/(B_SIZE)][i%B_SIZE]; // <<-- row-major order
    //values_1d[i] = values_2d[i%A_SIZE][i/A_SIZE]; // <<-- column-major order

    printf("values_1d[%d] = %d (0x%02X), values_2d[%d][%d] = %d (0x%02x)\n", 
        i, values_1d[i], values_1d[i], 
        i/B_SIZE, i%B_SIZE, 
        values_2d[i/B_SIZE][i%B_SIZE], values_2d[i/B_SIZE][i%B_SIZE]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
┌─(55:55:55)─(michael@lorry)─(~/tmp/hex)
└─► gcc -o main main.c; ./main
values_1d[0] = 18 (0x12), values_2d[0][0] = 18 (0x12)
values_1d[1] = 36 (0x24), values_2d[0][1] = 36 (0x24)
values_1d[2] = 70 (0x46), values_2d[0][2] = 70 (0x46)
values_1d[3] = 19 (0x13), values_2d[1][0] = 19 (0x13)
values_1d[4] = 53 (0x35), values_2d[1][1] = 53 (0x35)
values_1d[5] = 87 (0x57), values_2d[1][2] = 87 (0x57)
```

It's is in Row-major order.

Comment: Shouldn't I use the Row Major Order?

Comment: @Kiao Sorry, I had mistakes in my code. Fixed now. It's in Row-major order.

Comment: _both row-major and column-major_ - hmmm...  How awesome is that.

Comment: @ryyker I can see some comments in the code. Can you? :) It is the place where double slashes and grey color.:) Oh, and using these comment it can be configured for both variants! Glad you interested! ;)

Comment: @ryyker Added more details to explanation. Must be little better.

Comment: @Michael Thank you so much for your help. It was useful. I didnt know about the %02x. But I did my codes in another way, not sure if it correct.

Comment: @Michael Can you help me with my second question? How do I use the 1D Sbox in my functions?

Comment: @Kiao It is not clear what you are trying to do in your second question. Give more details on what is the output should be and what is the input data. For instance, statemt array is not described at all. Also I would suggest you to put all the information into a separate question. Otherwise, this question may be closed by the community, because answers which have been already posted here become invalid and mix with a new ones. One problem - one question.

Comment: @Michael Ok. I shall ask my question in another post. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you got to remember is that hexadecimal is just a way of presenting integer values, they are not stored as hexadecimal in the computer.

The second thing is that if you want to have a single array made out of a matrix, then the size of that single array would be (in your case) `SIZE_A * SIZE_B` entries big.

Then it's just a question of looping over the matrix, and setting the values in the array.

Answer (score 1):

These are my codes. Is it ok?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SIZE_A 16 //width
#define SIZE_B 16 //heightint Sbox[SIZE_A][SIZE_B] = {     //two dimensional array
{0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b,
0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76}, //*  initializers for row indexed by 0 
{0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf,
0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0}, //*  initializers for row indexed by 1
{0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1,
0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15}, //*  initializers for row indexed by 2
{0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2,
0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75},
{0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3,
0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84},
{0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39,
0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf},
{0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f,
0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8},
{0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21,
0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2},
{0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d,
0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73},
{0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14,
0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb},
{0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62,
0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79},
{0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea,
0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08},
{0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f,
0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a},
{0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9,
0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e},
{0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9,
0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf},
{0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f,
0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16}
};

int myarray[SIZE_A*SIZE_B]={0};

void print2darray(int Sbox[SIZE_A][SIZE_B])
{
int i,j;

for (i = 0; i < SIZE_A; i++ )
{
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE_B; j++ )
    {
        printf("SBox[%d][%d] = 0x%02X\n",i,j,Sbox[i][j]);
        }
    }

for (i = 0; i < SIZE_A; i++ )
{
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE_B; j++ )
    {
        myarray[i*SIZE_A+j]=Sbox[i][j];
        int value=myarray[i*SIZE_B+j];
        printf("myarray is [%d,%d] = 0x%02X\n",i,j,value);
        }
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{
    print2darray(Sbox);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a pointer to `int` and allocate memory and convert as shown...

```
int i, j, k=0;
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * SIZE_A * SIZE_B);

for(i = 0; i< SIZE_A; i++)
    for(j = 0; j< SIZE_B; j++)
    {
        ptr[k++] = Sbox[i][j];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem, if you want the dimensions changed, switch the outer and inner loop

```
int array1D[SIZEA * SIZEB];
int index1D = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < SIZEB; ++i)
{
  for(int j = 0; i < SIZEA; ++j)
  {
    array1D[index1D++] = Sbox[j][i];
  }
}
```

Nishith was faster

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:  *i am not sure how to do it. Because the values of the 2D arrays* ***are in hexadecimal.***

```
int Sbox[SIZE_A][SIZE_B] = {...
```

***int Sbox is your first clue***.  Good news, *No conversion necessary*.

The numbers represented within each of these blocks are just integers, shown in hexidecimal format.  Therefore, no conversion (i.e. from hex to int) is necessary, as they are *already* `int`.  All you have to do is pick one of the approaches *(described in another answer)* to re-arrange the values.